# Replacing symbolic derivatives in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, symbolic-computation

I have a symbolic function that looks like this

```
syms x y(x) h
fn(x) = y + (h^2*(diff(y(x), x) + 2))/2 + (h^5*diff(y(x), x, x, x, x))/120 + (h^3*diff(y(x), x, x))/6 + (h^4*diff(y(x), x, x, x))/24 + h*(2*x + y(x) - 1)
```

I'd like to replace all instances of derivatives of y with its first derivative, i.e.

```
subs(fn, sym('diff(y(x), x)'), dy)
```

where `dy` is already defined as

```
dy(x) = 2*x + y(x) - 1
```

The result  is the following:

```
ans(x) =

y + (h^2*(2*x + y(x) + 1))/2 + (h^5*diff(y(x), x, x, x, x))/120 + (h^3*diff(y(x), x, x))/6 + (h^4*diff(y(x), x, x, x))/24 + h*(2*x + y(x) - 1)
```

It replaces the first derivative, but not the higher derivatives. What I want is for the `h^5` term to have `(h^5*diff(dy(x), x, x, x)`. Is there any way to do that?

My current method is pretty hackish and involves converting the sym to a string, replacing first derivatives with `dy`, then converting back to a sym and evaluating to reduce the order of each term of the series by one, but it has to be recursive because at each stage derivatives of `dy` are then replaced by something containing `diff(y, ...)`. I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to deal with this.

Comment: Note, for clarity, that `diff(y(x), x, x, x, x)` is equivalent to `diff(y(x), x, 4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that Matlab treats things like `diff(y,x)` and `diff(y,x,2)` as distinct variables. It doesn't know how to substitute `diff(y,x)` into `diff(y,x,2)` because such a general operation for an abstract function (one with out an explicit definition, e.g., `y(x)`) is ill-defined.

How about something like this that performs substitution from the opposite end, starting with the highest order derivatives:

```
syms y(x) h
dy(x) = 2*x + y - 1
fn(x) = y + (h^2*(diff(y, x) + 2))/2 + (h^5*diff(y, x, 4))/120 + (h^3*diff(y, x, 2))/6 + (h^4*diff(y, x, 3))/24 + h*(2*x + y - 1)
fn2 = subs(fn, diff(y, x, 4), diff(dy, x, 3));
fn2 = subs(fn2, diff(y, x, 3), diff(dy, x, 2));
fn2 = subs(fn2, diff(y, x, 2), diff(dy, x));
fn2 = subs(fn2, diff(y, x), dy);
```

This returns

```
fn2(x) =

y(x) + (h^2*(2*x + y(x) + 1))/2 + (h^3*(2*x + y(x) + 1))/6 + (h^4*(2*x + y(x) + 1))/24 + (h^5*(2*x + y(x) + 1))/120 + h*(2*x + y(x) - 1)
```

Or you can leave `dy(x)` as an abstract symbolic expression initially:

```
syms y(x) dy(x) h
fn(x) = y + (h^2*(diff(y, x) + 2))/2 + (h^5*diff(y, x, 4))/120 + (h^3*diff(y, x, 2))/6 + (h^4*diff(y, x, 3))/24 + h*(2*x + y - 1)
fn2 = subs(fn, diff(y, x, 4), diff(dy, x, 3));
fn2 = subs(fn2, diff(y, x, 3), diff(dy, x, 2));
fn2 = subs(fn2, diff(y, x, 2), diff(dy, x));
fn2 = subs(fn2, diff(y, x), dy)
```

which returns

```
fn2(x) =

y(x) + (h^4*diff(dy(x), x, x))/24 + (h^2*(dy(x) + 2))/2 + (h^5*diff(dy(x), x, x, x))/120 + (h^3*diff(dy(x), x))/6 + h*(2*x + y(x) - 1)
```